# Keep XMPP connection(using smack) alive throughout application

Tags: android, xmpp

I am using the XMPP Connection(using smack) for chat in android application.I have made the connection with openfire and also i can send and receive the message.But the problem is that when i go in the XMPPClient.java activity then it made the connection.So i cant get any message till not go in that activity.So how can made the connection at the starting and then reuse at other activity.Code is in this 2 links [ConnectionSettings file](http://pastesite.com/39159) and the [chatscreen](http://pastesite.com/39162) in which we can do chat.In this link the comment line is also my questions so please also see that comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create global XMPPConnection object and Use below funciton and store in global XMPPConnection object and use that connection object everywhere. This is a sample gtalk example.

```
    public XMPPConnection login() throws XMPPException {

         ConnectionConfiguration config = new
         ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com",5222,"gmail.com");   
         config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.required);
         config.setTruststoreType("BKS");
         config.setTruststorePath("/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks");
         XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);        
        connection.connect();
        connection.login(username, password);
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.available);  
        connection.sendPacket(presence);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
     return connection;
}
```

Comment: can u please see the first link in my question in which i have i write the connection code.So how can i use that from any other activity?Or can you give some code for get the clear idea.

Comment: Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            connection.sendPacket(presence);
            xmppClient.setConnection(connection); in this code setconnection sunction is only in XMPPClient.java file so how can i use this code in different activity.

Comment: i don't want to execute the several time my code for made connection like in firstlink in question but just once run that code and then i can send and receive message without executing again.Have u seen my both link?

Comment: if i not made connection next time and try to send message then it will give me null pointer exception.So what u have got output by implementing?

Comment: Okay I got your problem. you want to say if you back from the application and again start application and try to send message then you get null pointer exception. Am I Correct? The solution is use Service for that.

Comment: yes exactly you got my problem.But at where i use the service and what can i do in that?can you help me because you already know the code and concept right.because i have never use the service.

Comment: Another solution is that when you setup your connection first time then store all the values in shared Preferences after that when you start you application then get all the preferences use that to reconnect in onCreate() function. So you get connection.

Comment: but even if just go back from XMPPCleint.java activity and  try to send message without executing code then also not work.it will give me null pointer exception.is it possible to store the connection object in shared preference?bcz otherthings are like port,uname,psw all are no need to save.

Comment: and i can not make connection in any other activity because it requires the object of class name with them made connection.may be you have seen the setconnection() method in xmppclient.java activity and it is set from setdialog.java so i cant write this connection at any other activity

Comment: You can make connection in any other activity all function writes in that activity and you can store parcelable object in shared preference. See this link: http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/06/parcelable-how-to-do-that-in-android.html

Comment: Try out with shared preference or service. Read tutorial of services you can get idea.

Comment: i have not enough reputation for chat.so can you chat on personal account if possible?bcz i need really hellp.and please see the firstlink again because in that xmppxlient class must be pass so how can i write this code in other activity?.and also in your given link only string value is parceble but i need the connection object to save.