# Run static block in java

Tags: java, xmpp, asmack

I have a static block in Java .How can i run it's static initialization block.

I see in this solution
[How to keep a XMPP connection stable on Android with (a)smack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080535/how-to-keep-a-xmpp-connection-stable-on-android-with-asmack)

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/smack/+/master/src/org/jivesoftware/smack/ReconnectionManager.java

```
static {
try {
    Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smack.ReconnectionManager");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    // problem loading reconnection manager
}
```

}

Comment: I think, just create constructor in this class

Comment: i can't access that class, it is in asmack packet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are calling SmackAndroid.init(Context), it is automatically calling these static classes you can check asmack code for clarification.

if you have any problem related to reconnection then you can check my answer,it is working for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23307341/2729665

Answer (score 0):

The static initializer block is run when the class is loaded. If there's nothing else to load the class you can call `Class.forName` to load it:

```
try {
    Class.forName("full.name.of.YourClass");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    // installation error? Class not found.
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: how can i know that the  ReconnectionManager class is running?

Comment: What is ReconnectionManager and how could it be running? If it uses a background thread, you can list the threads with the `jstack` tool or with a debugger.

Comment: i use Eclipse as my IDE

Comment: Great! Eclipse includes a debugger, doesn't it?