# Unable to reconnect XMPP on internet connectivity changed

Tags: java, android, xmpp

I am working on a chat application using asmack. I am able to establish xmpp connection and can send and receive messages properly. However, I wish to reconnect the XMPP connection if I change the internet connectivity from WIFI to #G and vice-versa. To listen to connectivity change, I have a broadcastreceiver which successfully notifies about connection changed. If I get connectivity as false, I check the xmpp connection for null or not null. If it's not null, I set it as null. And when internet is connected, I try to reconnect the xmpp connection. The main thing is that I start my app for first time, the xmpp connection is built successfully and the TLS handshake is done properly. I have specified the truststore logic as follows:

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    {
        connectionConfig.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
        connectionConfig.setTruststorePassword(null);
        connectionConfig.setTruststorePath(null);
    }
    else
    {
        connectionConfig.setTruststoreType("BKS");
        String path = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore");
        if(path == null)
        {
            path = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separator + "etc" + File.separator + "security" + File.separator + "cacerts.bks"; 
        }
        connectionConfig.setTruststorePath(path);
    }
```

This works fine for the first time and the TLS handshake gives me below result in logcat:

But when I try to reconnect as explained above, I do not get the success tag as received previously. Instead the errors received are as follows:

```
02-19 17:59:39.098: W/System.err(21977):    java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
02-19 17:59:39.133: W/System.err(21977):    at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
02-19 17:59:39.133: W/System.err(21977):    at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:146)
02-19 17:59:39.137: W/System.err(21977):    XMPPError establishing connection with server.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError establishing connection with server.
02-19 17:59:39.141: W/System.err(21977):    -- caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unable to create application data
02-19 17:59:39.160: W/System.err(21977):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
02-19 17:59:39.160: W/System.err(21977):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:473)
02-19 17:59:39.160: W/System.err(21977):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
02-19 17:59:39.160: W/System.err(21977):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
02-19 17:59:39.160: W/System.err(21977):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
02-19 17:59:39.160: W/System.err(21977):    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBytes(OutputStreamWriter.java:167)
02-19 17:59:39.160: W/System.err(21977):    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:158)
02-19 17:59:39.160: W/System.err(21977):    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:124)
02-19 17:59:39.160: W/System.err(21977):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.ObservableWriter.flush(ObservableWriter.java:48)
02-19 17:59:39.160: W/System.err(21977):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketWriter.writePackets(PacketWriter.java:196)
02-19 17:59:39.160: W/System.err(21977):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketWriter.access$000(PacketWriter.java:40)
02-19 17:59:39.160: W/System.err(21977):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketWriter$1.run(PacketWriter.java:76)
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.initReaderAndWriter(XMPPConnection.java:699)
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:835)
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:262)
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:43)
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:69)
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    Nested Exception: 
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unable to create application data
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:395)
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:647)
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:618)
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.initReaderAndWriter(XMPPConnection.java:666)
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPConnection.java:835)
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:262)
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:43)
02-19 17:59:39.164: W/System.err(21977):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:69)
```

Please help me to reconnect a failed xmpp connection and also let me know if there is any way to retrieve a session id so that I may check with the server whether any xmpp connection is alive with respect to the requested session id.

Comment: Are you using aSmack?

Comment: Checkout this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080535/how-to-keep-a-xmpp-connection-stable-on-android-with-asmack

Comment: Yes, i am using asmack library. I mentioned that in my description also.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem and i found the solution also. The solution goes as follows:

1) Firstly, i changed the truststore logic as given by me in my question to following

```
    connectionConfig.setTruststoreType("BKS");
    connectionConfig.setTruststorePath("/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks");
```

2) Then i added a connection listener for the XMPP connection.

3) I added a static block for ReconnectionManager so that the connection parameter is initialized.

When i ran the app on a real device, and then switched the internet connection from WIFI to 3G and vice-versa, the connection listener played its important role. It attempts for reconnection and the lost xmpp connection was again re-established.

One important thing, make sure to mention the connect method for making xmpp connection in the over-ridden method of connectionlistener i.e. connectionClosed().

Thanks Carnal for the help and co-operation given by you.

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

add this code:

static
{

```
    try 
    {
        Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smack.ReconnectionManager");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e3) 
    {
        Log.e("TextNS", "class not found exception maintain connnection 75 :   +e3.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e2) 
    {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

add connection listner to the xmppconnetion

to detect the connection status

Comment: This is actually what i added and got my issue resolved. Thanks for the valuable reply.