# Android - XMPP NotConnectedException

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, multiuserchat

On internet reconnect Xmpp throw error when I send message through MUC  `SmackException$NotConnectedException: Client is not, or no longer, connected.`

but when i manually finish activity and start the activity again it works fine.

Comment: you have implement `Reconnection Manager` in `xmpp` connection ?

Comment: Follow this link if you have not implemented Reconnection manager class https://stackoverflow.com/a/47605785/7589424